# Azure VM Extension provisioning has taken too long to complete

Tags: mysql, bash, azure, azure-rm-template, jsontemplate

When i am trying to deploy a template with extension i am getting timed out error as "***Provisioning of VM extension InstallLamp has timed out. Extension provisioning has taken too long to complete. The extension did not report a message***"

I am trying to install MySql through extension in a VM.

here is the extension code

```
{
"type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
"apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
"name": "[concat(variables('vmName'),'/', 'InstallMySQL')]",
"location": "[parameters('location')]",
"dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/',variables('vmName'))]"
],
"properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
    "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "1.7",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion":true,
    "settings": {
        "fileUris": [
            "<url of custom script>"
        ],
        "commandToExecute": "sampleScript.sh"
    }
}
```

Here is the sampleScript.sh code

```
sudo apt-get -y update
dbpass=12345678
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
echo "mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server/root_password password" $dbpass | sudo debconf-set-selections >>
echo "mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server/root_password_again password" $dbpass | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server-5.7
sudo apt-get -y install apache2 php7
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: the first question to ask would be - does this require any interaction? did you try running this on the vm without script extension?

Comment: I run the script without extension it works fine but i am getting error when i am trying do the same through the script extension

Comment: thats not the answer to my question. does it require any interaction?

Comment: No interaction is not required

Comment: Even when I am running only MySql Script through extensions it is throwing same time out error as above.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, the mistake you made is that the commands in the script are still interactive because of the command `sudo`. When you use the command `sudo`, it will need you to input the password of the root user.

And as I know, the VM extension already has the root permission to install the software. So you do not need to use the command `sudo` in your script. You just need to be sure the script is available and change it like this:

```
apt-get -y update
dbpass=12345678
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
echo "mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server/root_password password" $dbpass | debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server/root_password_again password" $dbpass | debconf-set-selections
apt-get -y install mysql-server-5.7
apt-get -y install apache2 php7
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Hi Charles, firstly thanks for your time. 
i have sorted out the error just couple of hours back.

script is fine with sudo and in json template at the extension resource I changed ** "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute"  ** to  ** "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions" **

Comment: @AsifTMd Any more questions? Do you solve the problem? Please let me know it.